# Why is this anagram function not correct?

Tags: javascript, iteration, anagram

Just got back my test for my Javascript class and I missed a question that I felt quite certain about.

We were supposed to make a function that returned true if two strings were anagrams, and false otherwise. I cant find an instance where this wouldn't work. I would appreciate any help!

This is what I had:

```
function isAnagram(str1, str2){
    if(str1.length !== str2.length){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        for(var i = 0; i < str1.length; i++){
            if(!str2.includes(str1[i])){
                return false;
            }
         }
         return true;
     }
}
```

Comment: Do you have tests ?

Comment: "Contains all the same letters" and "is an anagram" aren't the same things.

Comment: Because `isAnagram('aab', 'abb')` returns `true`, instead of `false`, for example.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the help guys. Is there any way that I can modify my code slightly to fix this issue?

Comment: @Jonas Anagram also doesn't mean "reverse of".

Comment: @deceze jup, still learning...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only checks that each letter of `str1` is present in `str2`, regardless of how many times they appear.

**EDIT**: It also doesn't check if `str2` has letters that don't appear in `str1`.

```js
function isAnagram(str1, str2) {
  if (str1.length !== str2.length) {
    return false;
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) {
      if (!str2.includes(str1[i])) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
}

console.log(isAnagram('hello', 'hlleo'), ', should be true'); // true: correct
console.log(isAnagram('bye', 'byee'), ', should be false'); // false: correct
console.log(isAnagram('byeb', 'byee'), ', should be false'); // true: incorrect
console.log(isAnagram('byeb', 'byte'), ', should be false'); // true: incorrect
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternative solution.

```js
const isAnagram = (s1, s2) => {
  return lowerify(s1) == lowerify(s2);
}

const lowerify = str => str.toLowerCase().split('').sort().join('');

console.log(isAnagram("Arrigo Boito", "Tobia Gorrio"));
console.log(isAnagram("abc", "CBa"));
console.log(isAnagram("deep", "depp"));
```

Answer (score 2):

It can't handle the case where you have two words, of equal length, using the same letters, but with different numbers of each letter.

This gives a false positive:

```
console.log(isAnagram("deep", "depp"))
```

Comment: Dang it, should have saw that. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Because your function would, for example, fail this test:

```
isAnagram('abba', 'abbb') === false
```

Comment: No. That's why I had the initial case where I checked their length

Comment: Right, I overlooked that

Answer (score 1):

Single characters can occur multiple times in your function, for example comparing `test` and `tttt` returns true.
One way to modify your function is to remove the character from `str2` each time one is found in the for loop:

```
function isAnagram(str1, str2){
  if(str1.length !== str2.length) return false;
  for(var i = 0; i < str1.length; i++){
    var found = str2.indexOf(str1[i]);
    if(found === -1) return false;
    str2 = str2.substr(0,found) + str2.substr(found + 1)
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Added a code sample, even though Kind user's solution is the nicer one.

Answer (score 1):

as a test case, your code would return success on this, but violate the rules of being an anagram :

```
isAnagram("ooaooa", "oooooa");
```

it just checks if the same amount of letters are present, and if every letter from word a is present in word b, but not the *count* of the letters in both words.

Answer (score 0):

Simply compare both the strings character by character and register how many matches you find. The total matches must be >= to the string length (to cater to the cases where the characters might be repeating e.g. b**oo**t)

```js
var i, j;
var z = 0;
function checkAnagram(str1, str2) {
    if (str1.length != str2.length) { return `${str1} and ${str2} are not anagram, lengths dont match!`; }
    else {
        for (i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < str2.length; j++) {
                if(str1[i] == str2[j]) {
               // console.log('matches',str1[i],str2[j]);
                z++;
                }
                }
            }
          //  console.log(z);
            if (z>=str1.length)
            return`${str1} and ${str2} are anagram!`;
            else return `${str1} and ${str2} are not anagram!`;
        }
}
console.log(checkAnagram('fired','fried'));
console.log(checkAnagram('logo','ogol'));
console.log(checkAnagram('abcd','abc'));
```